# Getting rows from one table that are related to each other throught another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
    COUNTRY
    -------------
    id
    name

    NEIGHBOUR
    -------------
    id
    id_country1
    id_country2
```

`id_country1` and `id_country2` are ids of countries in table `COUNTRY` that are related to each other.

How can I make a select statement so I get names of all countries that are neighbours to one particular country?

Comment: No, it's not homework. I'm past that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  COUNTRY.name AS name
FROM
  NEIGHBOUR
  INNER JOIN COUNTRY ON
    NEIGHBOUR.id_country1=COUNTRY.id
    OR NEIGHBOUR.id_country2=COUNTRY.id 
WHERE
    (NEIGHBOUR.id_country1=<your requested id>
    OR NEIGHBOUR.id_country2=<your requested id>)
    AND COUNTRY.id<><your requested id>
```